# Text Tkinter Python 3.8 - Контекстное меню

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, текст

Хочу написать аналог блокнота Windows на Python с некоторыми добавлениями. Но как я могу **реализовать вход в приложение по контекстному меню?**
Поясню. Допустим, у меня есть файл file.txt, который я хочу отредактировать через моё приложение. Я хочу нажать по файлу ПКМ, и в контекстном меню этого файла выбрать "Редактировать с помощью <моё приложение>". Возможно ли это организовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я ни разу это не использовал и не знаю, как объяснить. Попытаюсь привести пример.
Допустим, у меня установлен VS Code. Тогда у меня, при нажатии ПКМ по файлу (допустим, файлу .py), появляется контекстное меню. В этом контекстном меню есть кнопка "Открыть в Visual Studio Code". При её нажатии в программе Visual Studio Code открывается содержимое файла.
Как это можно реализовать через виджет tkinter.Text в Python? Чтобы также при нажатии, скажем на txt-файл, появлялось контекстное меню, с кнопкой "Редактировать с <моя программа>", при нажатии на которую открывалось бы мое приложение, а в Text

Comment: ...было содержимое файла